# Execute command with sudo and execute Bash script with sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

I was always thinking that to execute commands with `sudo` and to execute bash script with `sudo` were the same. But today I find that they are different. Here is what I've tested:

```
me@my_machine:~$ sudo echo $(whoami)
```

I execute the command from terminal and get the output: `me`. After reading this link: [Why does “sudo -u root echo `whoami`” not return root](https://superuser.com/questions/384544/why-does-sudo-u-root-echo-whoami-not-return-root), I understand this.

Then I create a bash script named `test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $(whoami)
```

And I execute this script: `sudo ./test.sh`, to my surprise, the output now becomes: `root`.

So executing commands with `sudo` and executing Bash scripts with `sudo` are different?

If I have a Bash script, containing the command `whoami`, have it be executed with `sudo`, how could I get `me`, instead of `root`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer explains what user executes the command substitution `$(whoami)` shown in the question.  In actuality, the construct `echo $(whoami)` would hopefully never be used since `whoami` on its own would be the correct way of outputting the username of the current user.

Calling `echo` on a command substitution is simply not needed, and may even under some circumstances *modify* the output of the command in the command substitution. Don't use `echo $(...)`.

Running `whoami` would output the username of the unprivileged user in the question, and `sudo whoami` would output `root`.

---

For the shell to run the command

```
sudo echo $(whoami)
```

it must first figure out what arguments to call `sudo` with.  `echo` is just a simple string, so the shell does nothing to it, but `$(whoami)` is a command substitution that needs to be expanded. It does this by executing `whoami` and replacing the command substitution with its output.  It is then ready to call `sudo`.

This means that `sudo` will be executed with `echo` and the output of `whoami` (which was executed as your unprivileged user) as arguments.

If you want to run `whoami` inside the command substitution *with* `sudo`, you can put it in a script and run the script with `sudo`, as you've done, or you may use an in-line script, as in

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "$(whoami)"'
```

Here, the `sh -c` script is run as root, so `whoami` will also run as root.

The point is that *the shell that runs `whoami`* is executing as the root user.

The shell that executes `whoami` in the first command, `sudo echo $(whoami)`, runs as your ordinary user, not root.